# Fetch and loop over unknown objects in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, generics

I've been working on generics in ASP.NET MVC for quite some time, and I've thought about generics on other languages, particularly in AngularJS.

Suppose I have 2 sample endpoints:

`www.listofstudents.com/all`
and
`www.listofteachers.com/all`

which will return 2 object type, either a `students` or `teachers`.

I want to know how to handle this scenario. The process will be:

1. Fetch from a desired endpoint.
2. Determine the object type.
3. Iterate through the `properties` of the object to create table headers.
4. Iterate through the values and display them in a table.

Here is what I have tried so far, just the typical request process in angular and using two different endpoints:

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("jsonApp",[]);

app.controller("jsonCtrl", ['$scope', '$http',function($scope, $http){
    $http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments")
        .success(function(response){
            $scope.records = response;
        });

    $http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        .success(function(response){
            $scope.posts = response;
        });

    }]);
```

**index.html**

```
<table ng-controller="jsonCtrl" class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>AuthorID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Body</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="post in posts | limitTo: 10">
            <td>{{post.userId}}</td>
            <td>{{post.title}}</td>
            <td>{{post.body}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Write some code and let us know how it goes.

Comment: That's the code I have written so far.

Comment: Cool code. Looks like it's working great.

Comment: I did not my code for any other purposes. It's just that I do not know how to handle the scenario of what I'm asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you're asking is how to get the property names for table headers, something like this should suffice (assuming each *post* has the same keys)

```
$http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then(function(response) {
    $scope.data = response.data;
    $scope.headers = Object.keys(response.data[0] || {});
});
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Then you can use `ng-repeat`

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="header in headers">{{::header}}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
        <td ng-repeat="prop in headers">{{::item[prop]}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The nested loop is to maintain the key order established in `headers`.

Comment: Thank you for a concise answer @Phil. I've been struggling on this for several hours. One more question though, is there a way to limit the fields? Thanks again.

Comment: @Cyval of course. You can use something like [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the `headers` array to filter out unwanted values