# Can you populate a table with Angular.js without hardcoding column names?

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple Angular.js application that grabs tabular data from a mysql database and shows it in a simple bootstrap table. I’m using this code below to show the table column names without hardcoding them individually…

```
HTML:
       <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr style="background:lightgrey">
             <th ng-repeat="column in columns"> {{ column }} </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
```

and in the controller I create ’$scope.columns’ with something like this…

```
    var columnNames = function(dat) {
        var columns = Object.keys(dat[0]).filter(function(key) {
          if (dat[0].hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof key == 'string') {
            return key;
          }
        });
        return columns;
    };

    DataFactory.getTables(function(data) {
        $scope.columns = columnNames(data);
        $scope.tables = data; 
    });
```

And this works as expected and it’s great, but what about the the rest of the data.. So for example, the body of my table currently looks like this…

```
HTML:
       <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="x in tables ">
            <td> {{ x.id}} </td>
            <td> {{ x.name }} </td>
            <td> {{ x.email }} </td>
            <td> {{ x.company }} </td>
        </tbody>
```

I’ve tried using two loops like this…

```
HTML:
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="x in tables">
            <td ng-repeat=“column in columns”> {{ x.column }} </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

But this code doesn’t work, So is it possible to populate a table with angular without hardcoding the column names in HTML, and if so whats the most efficient way to do so?

Comment: Might be a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357370/angularjs-building-a-dynamic-table-based-on-a-json

Comment: {{ x[column] }}  not {{ x.column }}

Comment: This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34604644/fetch-and-loop-over-unknown-objects-in-angularjs

Comment: @sdfacre is right {{ x[column] }} instead of {{ x.column }}

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thank you @sdfacre

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this https://jsfiddle.net/8w2sbs6L/.

```
<div data-ng-app="APP">
    <table ng-controller="myController" border=1>
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <td ng-repeat="column in columns">{{column}}</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in tables">
        <td ng-repeat="column in columns">{{x[column]}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


<script>

'use strict';

angular.module('APP', [])


.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.tables = [
        { 
            "column1":"row1-column1",
        "column2":"row1-column2",
            "column3":"row1-column3",
            "column4":"row1-column4" 
        },
        { 
            "column1":"row2-column1",
        "column2":"row2-column2",
            "column3":"row2-column3",
            "column4":"row2-column4" 
        }
    ];

    $scope.columns = [
        "column1",
      "column2",
        "column3",
        "column4" 
    ];
}]);

</script>
```